# Trying to create a bake substance script in maya pymel

Tags: python, plugins, maya, substance, pymel

I have been trying to figure out how to script my own bake script for substance materials to files in maya, or find some documentation somewhere that gives me the commands and the format it should be used in. Has anyone made a script using the substance commands that I could look at fro reference? All I have found is a list of these commands that I found in the substance plugin information:

```
sbs_IsSubstanceRelocalized()
sbs_SetBakeFormat()
sbs_GetGlobalTextureHeight()
sbs_GetEditionModeScale()
sbs_GetChannelsNamesFromSubstanceNode()
sbs_AffectTheseAttributes()
sbs_GetSubstanceBuildVersion()
sbs_SetEditionModeScale()
sbs_GetBakeFormat()
sbs_GetEngine()
sbs_GetGlobalTextureWidth()
sbs_GoToMarketPlace()
sbs_GetGraphsNamesFromSubstanceNode()
sbs_GetAllInputsFromSubstanceNode()
sbs_AffectedByAllInputs()
sbs_EditSubstance()
sbs_GetPackageFullPathNameFromSubstanceNode()
sbs_SetGlobalTextureWidth()
sbs_SetEngine()
sbs_SetGlobalTextureHeight()
```

Please help!

Comment: Can't you just do it in the GUI, and then check the MEL Script Editor output to see what Maya did?

Comment: I have tried that, even with echo commands on it doesn't show what i need. I wish it did =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short script I use to load a substance in mel script

```
// load plugin should be "substance" on windows
loadPlugin "libSubstance";
// create sbs node
string $sbsnode = `shadingNode -asTexture substance`;
// load sbsar with absolute path
setAttr($sbsnode+".package") -type "string" "/usr/autodesk/maya/substance/substances/Aircraft_Metal.sbsar";
```